# Make nginx send expire headers

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make nginx send expiration headers, I tried in two different ways:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)\?[0-9]+$ {
  expires max;
}
```

and

```
location / {
  if ($request_uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)\?[0-9]+$") {
    expires max;
    break;
  }
  #....
}
```

none of which worked. No expiration headers are sent whatsoever. Any ideas how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines actually worked, I was just testing them wrong. These lines correctly try to cache only timestamped resources (those with ?id at the end) and I was looking at non-timestamped ones.

Answer (score 2):

Location should on path only, without query string, so this shouldn't work.

Try the following :

```
location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires max;
}
```

or, at least, the following should work too :

```
location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
    expires max;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Test to make sure the locations block is being called by placing an additional directive in there..something like:

```
location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires max;
    auth_basic "Restricted, please login";
    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd.users;
}
```

If you're not presented with a auth prompt when requesting matching files then you can be certain that the block is not being called due to an earlier break or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

Are using nginx as a caching proxy?
If so be aware that upstream caching instructions are respected, but you can still instruct nginx not to using proxy_ignore_headers

```
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
```